# Perform function after a period of time

Tags: arduino-mega, library, digital

I am working on a project that I am supplying with voltage an LED through a digital pin (26) and I want the LED to be switched off after 4 seconds.

I am using Arduino Mega2560 and I am programming it using Arduino's IDE version 1.6.10. I have installed the SimpleTimer library .zip method but it does not seem to function.

**Code**

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

SimpleTimer timer;

void setup() {
pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(26, HIGH);


timerId = timer.setTimeout(4000, switchOff);
}

void switchOff() {
  digitalWrite(26, LOW);
}

void loop() {
}
```

The problem is that the LED stays just on (*digitalWrite(26, HIGH);*) instead of going to the *switchOff* function and turning off (*digitalWrite(26, LOW);*). I have also tried using Timer1 and Timer libraries but they also do not work. Can someone who has made any of the libraries work, provide me with some guidance?

Comment: You have to call timer.run() inside loop function.

Comment: It worked! Answer the question and I will choose your answer as the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `timer.run()` inside loop function.

The SimpleTimer library is more like a scheduler. You call at every so often, and it checks if there is any event that has expired.